# Table schema for page subsciptions

Tags: mysql, database-schema

I have a page subscription-like application where users can subscribe to pages. When a page is viewed, I want to show both the number of users subscribed to it and a list of the users.

Also when someone views a user's profile, they should be shown all the pages that the user is a subscriber of.

What I thought of is this:

```
Page
    id
    users (JSON format containing userIDs of all subscribed)

User
    id
    page_IDs (JSON format containing the IDs of the walls he is subscribed to)
```

I guess this is okay for very small scale applications. But when the site grows and there are more than 1000 subscribers for each page, decoding all that JSON data into arrays in PHP would not be a good idea at all.

Anyone with a better schema in mind?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Let's just say it was a good idea to ask about this...

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote that comment I didn't have time to also post an answer. Now I added one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your design is not very good. It's actually kind of bad. In principle, the goal is to have a schema that fullfills **AT LEAST** the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

You're in the situation in which a page can have multiple users subscribed to it and a user can be subscribed to multiple pages. So between the table `users` and the table `pages` there's a many-to-many relationship.

In these situations, the best solution is to have a third table that will make the connection between the two. Usually this table consists of only 2 columns:

- column 1 contains primary keys from table 1 a.k.a. foreign keys
- column 2 contains primary keys from table 2 a.k.a. foreign keys

There are exceptions to this, but in general this is how you would design/normalize something like this.

More specific to your situation:

```
pages
-------------------------
page_id
<other columns>
PRIMARY KEY(page_id)

users
-------------------------
user_id
<other columns>
PRIMARY KEY(page_id)

subscriptions
-------------------------
page_id
user_id
PRIMARY KEY(page_id,user_id)
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually did think of this. But wont there be like ALOT of records in this third table then?

Comment: @AninditKarmakar Yes, there's a high chance that there will be. But, as long as those columns are indexed and as long as they're integers (they're IDs, so it's OK), you won't have any space and/or performance problems. RDBMS-es are built and optimized to efficiently work in all kinds of situations. Unless we're talking about hundreds of millions of rows (and I doubt that we do), you'll be fine.